How to edit the DumpSave data file later?
My understanding is, if you store something through DumpSave in a file, and then, on a later session, try to use the same file to save some more data, the older data will get erased. Is this true? Is there a way to avoid this so that the data in file is appended rather than overwritten over different sessions?
This is what I tried.
filename = "testExpr.mx"
expr = x^2
DumpSave[filename, expr]

After this, I do evaluation->quit kernel-> local. Then I do.
filename = "testExpr.mx";
expr2 = xy;
DumpSave[filename, expr2];
Get[filename];
expr
expr2

Output is:
expr
xy

That is, the new data in the new session was overwritten. Is this how DumpSave works? As a storage for data that can be edited only while the session in which it was created lasts? Is it possible to edit it later using a built in method?
I can think of some ways to modify it to suit my case. For example, defining a function that first reads the file and then appends the new data rather than overwriting on it.

I think that PersistentObject is closer to what you are looking for,

I believe .mx files have a structure and you cannot simply append new data. (But I've never tried it.) Have you considered Save[]?
